# Facebook Graph API does not return old post comments if we use since

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the feeds from facebook using grpah API by these steps:

1. Created one post in FB at 24-06-2017 9:00 AM.
2. I included a since parameter = - 1 day in request.(that means need all the feeds (25-06-2017 9:00 AM onwords) from from API).
3. Called API to get list of feeds at 26-06-2017 9:00 AM.
4. Did not get any feeds from API why because did not find any posts in between 25-06-2017 and 26-06-2017.
5. Now create a comment for existing (24-06-2017 day) post.
6. Now again fetch the details with same request param(since=-1 day).
7. Did not get feeds from API response why because API is considering always post created time not updated time.

Our expectation is we should get the feed with updated comment details.
Right now API is considering only post created_time not updated_time.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

To get all the desired information you should have a look at the Facebook Webhooks (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks). They notify your application if a new post or comment is made and you can then poll the needed information, because you have to right ids.

There is no way to resolve your problem with simple polling the Graph API. At least without running into request limits ...